# How to determine what gfortran is vectorizing

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to write a massively parallel monte carlo code part of which will be exported to a xeon phi coprocessor. To ensure that I am using the coprocessor efficiently, I would like to see which parts of my code the compiler, currently gfortran, is able to vectorize. I understand I can do this using the ifort commane -vec-report. However, I won't have access to the coprocessor for about a month, and therefore am stuck with gfortran for the time being. However, I would like to start optimizing now if possible. Unfortanately, I cannot seem to find the command line flag for gfortran that tells me which part of the code is being vectorized. Is there one. If so, what is it?

thanks

Comment: extremely short answer: look at `man gcc`

Answer (score 2):

You can try, if `-fopt-info` suits you needs.

You can get more output by using `-fopt-info-all` which includes information on successfull and missed optimization.

Comment: This way is probably more useful, just one needs to be aware there will be more stuff than just the vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

The vectorizer can be instructed to be verbose and report what it does:

`-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=n`

where larger integer `n` means more verbose report.

For more see http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html

(It took me 1 minute to google it).

Comment: This doesn't report anything for my code, which get's a successful report from -fopt-info.

Comment: It does report for my code. What `n` did you use? And did you enable vectorization at all (`-O3` is required)?

Comment: I tried all `n` from 1 to 10. Is this maybe, because I get a loop vectorization for a `forall` loop? I did `-O3`, but this doesn't enable `-ftree-vectorize`. So I added it manually.

Comment: It does report also for `forall` to me. Even if it does not vectorize it in the end. gfortran 4.8 -O3

Comment: Weird, I can confirm it doesn't print anything for gfortran-4.9 or 4.7.