# vectorized sum in Fortran

Tags: fortran, sse, gfortran, simd, avx

I am compiling my `Fortran` code using `gfortran` and `-mavx` and have verified that some instructions are vectorized via `objdump`, but I'm not getting the speed improvements that I was expecting, so I want to make sure the following argument is being vectorized (this single instruction is ~50% of the runtime).

I know that some instructions can be vectorized, while others cannot, so I want to make sure this can be:

`sum(A(i1:i2,ir))`

Again, this single line takes about 50% of the runtime since I am doing this over a very large matrix. I can give more information on *why* I am doing this, but suffice it to say that it is necessary, though I can restructure the memory if necessary (for example, I could do the sum as `sum(A(ir,i1:i2))` if that could be vectorized instead.

Is this line being vectorized? How can I tell? How do I force vectorization if it is not being vectorized?

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, I now realize that I can check on the vectorization of this summation via `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose` and see that this is *not* vectorizing. I have restructured the code as follows:

```
tsum = 0.0d0
tn = i2 - i1 + 1
tvec(1:tn) = A(i1:i2, ir)
do ii = 1,tn
    tsum = tsum + tvec(ii)
enddo
```

and this **ONLY** vectorizes when I turn on `-funsafe-math-optimizations`, but I do see another 70% speed increase due to vectorization. The question still holds: Why does `sum(A(i1:i2,ir))` not vectorize and how can I get a simple `sum` to vectorize?

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644203/how-to-determine-what-gfortran-is-vectorizing

Comment: Fortran accesses arrays in a column-major way, i.e. your current version is much faster than `sum(A(ir,i1:i2))`. Your current version accesses a contiguous chunk of memory.

Comment: Regarding your edit: very interesting. I would've expected the sum to be vectorized. Did you do actual benchmarks with sum vs loop? And have you played around with optimization switches? Update: [have you tried -ffast-math](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-01/msg00441.html)?

Comment: OpenMP 4 "simd" clause and reduction?

Comment: You can also try `-fopt-info` to get more information (this is documented in `man gcc`). I guess, there is some form of loop unrolling.

Comment: I suppose Andras' responce is very accurate. Try SUM in combination with -ffast-math switched on for given compilation unit. With other vectorizing compilers the rules might be more sophisticated; but even with ifort you often have to use OMP simd directive (or alternatively fp:fast) to make reductions stably vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I am not able to make use of the vectorization unless I include `-ffast-math` or `-funsafe-math-optimizations`.

The two code snippets I played with are:

```
tsum = 0.0d0
tvec(1:n) = A(i1:i2, ir)
do ii = 1,n
    tsum = tsum + tvec(ii)
enddo
```

and

```
tsum = sum(A(i1:i2,ir))
```

and here are the times I get when running the first code snippet with different compilation options:

```
10.62 sec ... None
10.35 sec ... -mtune=native -mavx
 7.44 sec ... -mtune-native -mavx -ffast-math
 7.49 sec ... -mtune-native -mavx -funsafe-math-optimizations
```

Finally, with these same optimizations, I am able to vectorize `tsum = sum(A(i1:i2,ir))` to get

```
 7.96 sec ... None
 8.41 sec ... -mtune=native -mavx
 5.06 sec ... -mtune=native -mavx -ffast-math
 4.97 sec ... -mtune=native -mavx -funsafe-math-optimizations
```

When we compare `sum` and `-mtune=native -mavx` with `-mtune=native -mavx -funsafe-math-optimizations`, it shows a ~70% speedup. (Note that these were only run once each - before we publish we will do true benchmarking on multiple runs).

I do take a small hit though. My values change slightly when I use the `-f` options. Without them, the errors for my variables (`v1`, `v2`) are :

```
v1 ... 5.60663e-15     9.71445e-17     1.05471e-15
v2 ... 5.11674e-14     1.79301e-14     2.58127e-15
```

but with the optimizations, the errors are :

```
v1 ... 7.11931e-15     5.39846e-15     3.33067e-16
v2 ... 1.97273e-13     6.98608e-14     2.17742e-14
```

which indicates that there truly is something different going on.

Comment: Well, I guess one source of `unsafe`ness of the optimizations might come from rearranging the order of operations. I don't think errors on the scale of machine precision are lethal.

Answer (score 0):

Your explicit loop version still does the FP adds in a different order than a vectorized version would.  A vector version uses 4 accumulators, each one getting every 4th array element.

You could write your source code to match what a vector version would do:

```
tsum0 = 0.0d0
tsum1 = 0.0d0
tsum2 = 0.0d0
tsum3 = 0.0d0
tn = i2 - i1 + 1
tvec(1:tn) = A(i1:i2, ir)
do ii = 1,tn,4   ! count by 4
    tsum0 = tsum0 + tvec(ii)
    tsum1 = tsum1 + tvec(ii+1)
    tsum2 = tsum2 + tvec(ii+2)
    tsum3 = tsum3 + tvec(ii+3)
enddo

tsum = (tsum0 + tsum1) + (tsum2 + tsum3)
```

This *might* vectorize without `-ffast-math`.

FP add has multi-cycle latency, but one or two per clock throughput, so you need the asm to use multiple vector accumulators to saturate the FP add unit(s).  Skylake can do two FP adds per clock, with latency=4.  Previous Intel CPUs do one per clock, with latency=3.  So on Skylake, you need 8 vector accumulators to saturate the FP units.  And of course they have to be 256b vectors, because AVX instructions are as fast but do twice as much work as SSE vector instructions.

Writing the source with 8 * 8 accumulator variables would be ridiculous, so I guess you need `-ffast-math`, or an OpenMP pragma that tells the compiler different orders of operations are ok.

Explicitly unrolling your source means you have to handle loop counts that aren't a multiple of the vector width * unroll.  If you put restrictions on things, it can help the compiler avoid generating multiple versions of the loop or extra loop setup/cleanup code.

Comment: If tn is not a multiple of 4, does that do loop miss some or go too far?

Comment: @Laurbert515: yes, one or the other.  If I knew Fortran, I could tell you which. :P  This is the issue my last paragraph describes: unrolling leads to needing cleanup code to handle the odd few iterations.  Letting the compiler worry about this by using `-ffast-math` or OpenMP is going to save you a lot of debugging (or at least dev time doing the thinking to make sure you don't introduce bugs in the first place.)